# podman cannot see all running containers

Tags: podman

At the job just started using containers.   Putting 10 seconds of thought into the set up, I built out a RHEL 8 system using podman.   There are two different non-root users running containers.  Running "podman ps" as each user sees running containers, grand total of 3.   root sees nothing running.   Why?  Shouldn't root be able to see a running container same as the owners? I have found nothing to indicate that this should happen or is just a rookie mistake.   Any documents would help.

Answer (score 1):

A user is only able to list the containers that belong to that user.
So root sees no containers running if they all have been run by non-root users.

We only way to list all the running container IDs that I've found is by executing the following command:

```
$ sudo find /var/run/crun/ /var/run/user/ -type f -name status 2>/dev/null 
/var/run/crun/dfdd7076246d758a144a269a32eed89270c55e4a09c6b8a75162f5e01d054871/status
/var/run/user/1000/crun/41f5a7c3724932e2520340c3176ed5d1bed19fcefeaff3e474ffc20c23c67052/status
/var/run/user/1000/crun/9b7a2b1fd9463219258b8753bf2a77d440a37f6f9768f3abcc8a7a2777e54719/status
```

Tested on Fedora 35 and podman 3.4.1

Comment: If your operating system is using __systemd__ that is recent enough, it is possible to use `sudo systemd-run  --machine=username@  ...` or `sudo machinectl shell username@ ...` instead. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71253706/757777