# How to list rootless containers of ALL the users?

Tags: podman

Is there a command to show the containers and images present in the server? That means for root and all the users (rootless containers)?

```
su -
podman container ps --all
```

shows only root's containers.

I expected root to be able to see all the other containers.

Comment: Not exactly what you ask for but to list all images for one specific user: `sudo machinectl shell username@ /bin/bash -c "podman images"`

Comment: I believe there is no built-in command to list them... `machinectl` has been very useful for me, much better than `su`. Thanks for trying ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any command to list all containers for all users, but you could list all containers for an arbitrary user:

```
sudo systemd-run --machine=username@ --quiet --user --collect --pipe --wait podman container ps --all
```

(a recent version of **systemd** is needed for the command above).

You could also use `machinectl`

```
$ sudo -i
# machinectl shell username@
Connected to the local host. Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session.
$ podman container ps --all
```

Both executables belong to the systemd project.

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/systemd-run
systemd-249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/machinectl 
systemd-container-249.9-1.fc35.x86_64
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five)
```

As to why not use `su` see

Quote *Why can't I run rootless Podman containers when I log into a user via sudo or su?* from https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/sudo-rootless-podman

See also https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#30-podman-run-fails-with-erro0000-xdg_runtime_dir-directory-runuser0-is-not-owned-by-the-current-user-or-error-error-creating-tmpdir-mkdir-runuser1000-permission-denied

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using plain `su` instead of `sudo machinectl`:

```
su myuser -P -l -c "podman ps -a"
```

> Reason: I got high cpu/mem usage from `/usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon` by doing the 'machinectl'-trick above.

I ran it inside a tmux monitor script (every 10seconds) which shouldn't be too hard. Just check `tail -f /var/log/syslog` for the following repetitive phrases in case of doubt:

```
Feb 24 11:06:55 2wa systemd[1]: Started Shell for User git.
Feb 24 11:06:55 2wa systemd[1]: Started Session 391 of user git.
Feb 24 11:06:56 2wa systemd[4716]: Started podman-38205.scope.
Feb 24 11:06:56 2wa systemd[1]: session-391.scope: Succeeded.
Feb 24 11:06:56 2wa systemd[4716]: podman-38205.scope: Succeeded.
Feb 24 11:06:56 2wa systemd[1]: container-shell@7.service: Succeeded.
```

Possible reasons: `loginctl enable linger` (which is used often in combination with podman) causes overlapping shell-sessions when machinectl is called repeatedly within the lingering time.

Comment: `sudo machinectl` is recommended. `su` is not recommended. The reasons are explained in https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/sudo-rootless-podman . See also https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#30-podman-run-fails-with-erro0000-xdg_runtime_dir-directory-runuser0-is-not-owned-by-the-current-user-or-error-error-creating-tmpdir-mkdir-runuser1000-permission-denied