# Docker container list shows empty after reboot the linux server (rhel 8)

Tags: linux, docker, systemd, podman, rhel8

I have configured podman with systemd service in my Linux server(rhel 8). I have enabled the automatic restart option to the container after rebooting the Linux server(rhel 8) followed these instructions.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/building_running_and_managing_containers/assembly_porting-containers-to-systemd-using-podman_building-running-and-managing-containers

The container has run properly no issues occurred, after rebooting this server, the running container list does not show for the non-root user. But the root user, running container list has shown.

Also, checked the docker ps -a command, the container has shown in an exited state list for non-root users but in the root user same container has shown in the running state list.

Could you please suggest a solution for showing the running container list to non-root users after rebooting the server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [podman cannot see all running containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136750/podman-cannot-see-all-running-containers)

Comment: Try `loginctl enable-linger <username>` or maybe `sudo loginctl enable-linger <username>`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run - `systemcl --user start container-*.service` and then
`podman ps` to make sure the container runs.

Then, check the podman version `podman version`.

If podman version is 1.6 or 1.8 you should upgrade to version 2.0 or above.

If `podman ps` shows empty after reboot and the linux server is RHEL 8.2,
rhel 8.2 has issues with podman 1.6, which was fix after update to podman version 4.2.0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32437842)